# CS50 Caesar Prints Random Characters

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I'm a little confused with this problem, because I got it to work and submitted and got full credit, but the code only words when I print the initial variables before the loop. This code works:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    // c = (p + k) % 26, where c is result text, p is input and k
    // is key

    //considers if arg count is two
    if (argc == 2) {
        int n = strlen(argv[1]);
        int check = 0;

        if (isdigit(argv[1][0])) {
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) || argv[1][i] == '0') {
                    check++;
                } else {
                    check--;
                }
            }
        }

        // verifies all characters are numeric
        if (check != n - 1) {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        // returning 1 identifies an error and exits the program
        return 1;
    }

    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    printf("%i\n", key);
    printf("%s\n", plaintext);

    int m = strlen(plaintext);

    printf("%i\n", m);

    char ciphertext[m];
    int usekey = (key % 26);
    printf("%i\n", key);

    // NEED to figure out how to handle wrap around
    // need to understand ASCII
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int c = plaintext[i];

        //encrypts upper case letters
        if (c >= 65 && c <= 90) {
            //incorporates wrap around for uppercase
            if (c + usekey >= 90) {
                int val = 90 - c;
                int key2 = usekey - val;
                char cipher = 64 + key2;
                ciphertext[i] = cipher;
            }
            //considers if key works fine
            else {
                char cipher = c + usekey;
                ciphertext[i] = cipher;
            }
        }
        //encrypts lower case letters
        else if (c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
            //incorporates wrap around for lowercase
            if (c + usekey >= 122) {
                int val = 122 - c;
                int key2 = usekey - val;
                char cipher = 96 + key2;
                ciphertext[i] = cipher;
            } else {
                char cipher = c + usekey;
                ciphertext[i] = cipher;
            }
        } else {
        //encrypts punctuation
            ciphertext[i] = c;
        }
        printf("*\n");
    }

    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);

}
```

However, this code, does not work (for encrypts `a` as `b` using 1 as key, and for `world, say hello!` as `iadxp, emk tqxxa!` using 12 as key). It randomly prints different characters after the correct answer, and I cannot figure out why.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    // c = (p + k) % 26, where c is result text, p is input and k
    // is key

    //considers if arg count is two
    if (argc == 2) {
        int n = strlen(argv[1]);
        int check = 0;

        if (isdigit(argv[1][0])) {
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) || argv[1][i] == '0') {
                    check++;
                } else {
                    check--;
                }
            }
        }

        // verifies all characters are numeric
        if (check != n - 1) {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        // returning 1 identifies an error and exits the program
        return 1;
    }

    int key = atoi(argv[1]);

    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    int m = strlen(plaintext);

    char ciphertext[m];
    int usekey = (key % 26);

    // NEED to figure out how to handle wrap around
    // need to understand ASCII
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int c = plaintext[i];

        //encrypts upper case letters
        if (c >= 65 && c <= 90) {
            //incorporates wrap around for uppercase
            if (c + usekey >= 90) {
                int val = 90 - c;
                int key2 = usekey - val;
                char cipher = 64 + key2;
                ciphertext[i] = cipher;
            }
            //considers if key works fine
            else {
                char cipher = c + usekey;
                ciphertext[i] = cipher;
            }
        }
        //encrypts lower case letters
        else if (c >= 97 && c <= 122) {
            //incorporates wrap around for lowercase
            if (c + usekey >= 122) {
                int val = 122 - c;
                int key2 = usekey - val;
                char cipher = 96 + key2;
                ciphertext[i] = cipher;
            } else {
                char cipher = c + usekey;
                ciphertext[i] = cipher;
            }
        }
        //encrypts punctuation
        else {
            ciphertext[i] = c;
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
}
```

Comment: missing zero terminator? maybe do: `char ciphertext[m + 1]; ciphertext[m] = '\0'; /* no more changes */`

Comment: regarding: `int n = strlen(argv[1]);`  1) the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` NOT a `int`.  2) the value returned from `strlen()` is the index to the NUL termination byte and indexes start at 0, not 1.  2)  regarding: `for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)`  This skips checking the first char of the command line parameter.  Suggest: `for( size_t i = 0; i<n; i++ )`

Comment: this convoluted code: `if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) || argv[1][i] == '0')
                {
                    check++;
                }
                else
                {
                    check--;
                }`  could be replaced with: `if( isdigit( argv[1][i] ) ) { check++; }`  and `if (check != n - 1)`  replaced with: `if( check != n )`  then eliminate: `if (isdigit(argv[1][0]))
        {`

Comment: regarding `else if (c >= 97 && c <= 122)`  using hard coded values, like this, limits the encoding the ASCII.  and is difficult to understand.  Suggest: `else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')`  An even better approach would be to use the function `isalpha()` from the header file: `ctype.h`

Answer (score 0):

I think your if conditions is not works as it should be. you can print 'argv[1][i]' and see the problem. here is my code may help you.

```
bool isNumber(char number[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (; number[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(number[i]))    //check if there is something that is not digit
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    if (argc == 2 && isNumber(argv[1]) == 1)
    {
        int k = atoi(argv[1]);
        string plainText, chipherText;
        plainText = get_string("plaintext: ");
        printf("ciphertext: ");
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plainText) ; i < n; i++)
        {
            // checking if it is lowercase 97 = a to 112 = z and if it + 13 characters along.
            if (plainText[i] >= 'a' && plainText[i] <= 'z')
            {
                printf("%c", (((plainText[i] - 'a') + k) % 26) + 'a'); // print out lowercase with key
            } // if it it between uppercase A and Z
            else if (plainText[i] >= 'A' && plainText[i] <= 'Z')
            {
                printf("%c", (((plainText[i] - 'A') + k) % 26) + 'A'); // print out uppercase with key
            }

            else

            {
                printf("%c", plainText[i]);
            }
        }

        printf("\n");

        return 0;
    }
    else if (argc != 2 || isNumber(argv[1]) == 0)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You allocate `m` bytes for `cyphertext`, which is not enough for the null terminator, which you do not set either, causing *random characters* to appear after the encrypted output. This is actually undefined behavior, so anything can happen including a program crash.

You do not need to store the encrypted text, just output it one byte at a time.
Also do not use ASCII values such as `65` and `90`, use character constants `'A'` and `'Z'` that are much more readable.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        // returning 1 identifies an error and exits the program
        return 1;
    }
    char *p;
    int key = strtol(argv[1], &p, 10);
    if (*p || p == argv[1]) {
        printf("caesar: invalid argument: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    // assuming ASCII
    for (size_t i = 0; plaintext[i]; i++) {
        int c = plaintext[i];

        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            c = 'A' + (c - 'A' + key) % 26;
        } else
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            c = 'a' + (c - 'a' + key) % 26;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    free(plaintext);
    return 0;
}
```